# Why does SharePoint 2013 Search append "text/html; charset=utf-8 " to some ContentTypes and how can it be avoided?

Tags: 2013, search, content-type

I have a question according the Search in SharePoint 2013. My Search does append some strange "Types" to the ContentTypes. For example Documents with a Content Type with the Parent Content Type "Page" have sometimes (not always) the prefix `text/html; chareset=utf-8`. [image: In the Picture: putting out some ContentTypes from the search including <code>text/html; charset=utf-8 Article Page</code>]
*In the Picture: putting out some ContentTypes from the search including `text/html; charset=utf-8 Article Page` and `Page`*

As you can see: a document with a Content Type with the parent CT Document is shown with the prefix `application/pdf`

My Question is: Why does SharePoint append those strange Texts and how can i get rid of them?

Comment: How is your content source configured?

Comment: Updated the question with a picture showing the configuration of my content source

Comment: I've honestly never seen this and am not sure how to reproduce it. Which zones are those URL's in and are they configured for Windows Auth?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just ran into the same issue - here is how you can configure it to show the display names.

On the page with the search results (search for e.g. *):

- click on the settings wheel on top
- click on edit page
- in the navigation zone on the left: on the refinement webpart click on "edit web part"
- now on the right side the web part properties open - click on "choose refiners"
- on the right side you should see your current refiner "ContentType" which shows the weird results. If you want to show the display name of the ContentType you must select "SPContentType" from the left.

Here is a screenshot the shows the preview (only shows preview if you have searched for something on the page, e.g: *)

[image: Refinement configuration for SharePoint Search Refinement Panel]

As your post is already quite old - I hope this will help others :)

Comment: Thank you very much. It is realy because the mime type is mapped to the alias of the type "ContentType" wheras the SPContentType is not. My Refiners are now displayed correctly.

Comment: Another reason to hate Microsoft lol, however thank you!! Between ContentType and ContentTypeID it's hard to think there is another field hidden somewhere else.